# How to Get Style from Resource Dictionary in code-behind into UserControlLibrary?

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary

I have an User Control Library, with some Resource Dictionaries. Code:

```
<ResourceDictionary   ... >
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MyButtonBackground" EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FF654073" Offset="0.084"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF8A6093" Offset="0.929"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>


    <Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type MyButton}" >
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MyButtonBackground}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then I have a class to load the Resource Dictionary. Basically:

```
return (ResourceDictionary)Application.LoadComponent(new System.Uri("/MyAssembly;component/Themes/Default.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative))
```

Now, in the UserControl class, after getting the ResourceDictionary, I want to load the Style directly. How can I do that?

```
this.Style = ((Style)MyResourceDictionary["MyButtonStyle"]); // Don't work
```

However:

```
this.Background = ((Brush)MyResourceDictionary["MyButtonBackground"]);   // Works
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the exception you're getting for the first one? Based on your description, if `this` is a `UserControl`, you're getting an exception because the `Style` you are trying to apply is only applicable to a `MyButton`.

If you are trying to create a custom `Control` in WPF (which has a much different approach than a `UserControl`), then you're doing more work than you need to.

First, you'd create your custom control as a class (no XAML page):

```
public class MyButton : Button
{
    static MyButton()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(MyButton),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyButton)));  
    }
}
```

And then, in your `RessourceDictionary`, remove the `x:Key` from the `Style`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type MyButton}" >
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MyButtonBackground}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
</Style>
```

Finally, your `ResourceDictionary` needs to be included in the `Project_Root\Themes\generic.xaml` theme dictionary. You would then not need to get the resources from code at all.

For further reading, [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14340/Creating-a-look-less-custom-control-in-WPF) has a pretty good tutorial for creating a custom WPF control.

Comment: "this", in my example, is the MyButton : UserControl class.

Comment: Okay, so what exception are you getting?

Comment: So setting the `Background` explicitly in code behind works, but not applying a `Style`? Sounds like you are explicitly setting the properties in XAML. Which will have higher precedence than the `Style` values.